# Drawing half a square with Python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Good day,

I'm trying to write this python code for this two part problem and here is what I have so far. How somebody be able to help me finish it and or correct it? 
[image: The Question]

Here is my attempt:

```
#Question 11a
Print("Question 11a")
import turtle
s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

def halfSquare(t, length):
    for i in range(2)
    t.down()
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(90)

#Question 11b
print("Question 11b")
def halfSqaures(t, initial, increment, reps):
    halfSquare(length):
```

Please help!!

Comment: So what problem does your code have?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a bit of help on the first part, but I won't write the code because this is *your* homework, not mine.

In your `halfSquare` function you have a `SyntaxError` (you're missing the `:` on the end of the `for` statement) and an `IndentationError` (the code inside the `for` loop). Also, `t.right(90)` should be `t.left(90)`.

BTW, you can put `turtle.mainloop()` at the end of your program to wait for the user to close the window.

---

Ok. I see you're having some difficulties, so I'll post a fully-working program for you. But *please* try to understand how it works.

```
import turtle

print("Question 11a")

t = turtle.Turtle()

def halfSquare(t, length):
    t.down()
    for i in (0, 1):
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(90)

#halfSquare(t, 100)

print("Question 11b")
def halfSquares(t, initial, increment, reps):
    length = initial
    for i in range(reps):
        halfSquare(t, length)
        length += increment

halfSquares(t, 20, 20, 10)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I just made the changes you asked for and here is what I have: #Question 11a
Print("Question 11a")
import turtle
s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

def halfSquare(t, length):
    for i in range(2):
    t.down()
    t.forward(length)
    t.left(90)
    turtle.mainloop()
#Question 11b
print("Question 11b")
def halfSqaures(t, initial, increment, reps):
    halfSquare(length):
Please let me know what else do I need to add.

Comment: You should try calling the `halfSquare` function. Eg, `halfSquare(t, 100)` to see that it works. BTW, there's not much point posting multiple lines of Python code in comments because the indentation gets lost. But you could append your new version to the end of your question. As for Question 11b, experiment with some `for` loops and see what happens. It's not too hard to do.

Comment: Alright so I finally got part A to run, but I don't know how to do part B. Any help would be great!!#Question 11a
import turtle
s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

def halfSquare(t, length):
    for i in range(2):
        t.down()
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(90)
    
halfSquare(t, 100)

     

#Question 11b
print("Question 11b")
def halfSqaures(t, initial, increment, reps):
    halfSquare(t, 100)
    for i in range(reps):

Comment: @ebramk: I've added some code to my answer. If it helps you, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.